# Updating contents of div after clicking on table row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have datatable and a div, where I want to load information about the order with ajax after clicking on the row of the datatable.

assets/javascript/orders.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orders').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true
    });

    $('#orders tbody tr').each( function() {
        this.onclick = function() {
            $('#order_info').load(
                ???
            )
        };
    })

})
```

orders/list.html.erb:

```
    <table id="orders">
      <tbody>
      <% @orders.each do |order| %>
        <tr data-orderrow=<%= order[:id] %>>
        </tr>
      <% end %>

      </tbody>
    </table>

<div id="order_info" style="float: right;">
</div>
```

If my approach is good, what should I put in the place of ??? in my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call to some controller and action that returns json data. Then consume that data, and display the json that comes back.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // best to 'cache' the jquery queries you use more than once.
  var $orders = $("#orders"),
      $orderInfo = $("#orderInfo");

  $orders.dataTable({
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "bJQueryUI": true
  });

  // it is best not to attach one click even to each 'tr', so instead
  //  I've added a single click event to the entire table, and then
  //  determine the closest 'tr' to get the orderId from it. 
  $orders.click(function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target), $order, orderId; // get the element that was clicked
    $order = $target.closest("tr");
    orderId = $order.attr("data-orderrow");

    $.getJSON("/orders/"+orderId+".json",function(orderData){
      // do something with orderData, which is an object with the order data
    });
  });  
})
```

Then in your controller, you could do something like this. You'll need to fill this out in the best way for your application:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "show" }
      format.json { render :json => order }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But one question, what if wanted to use rails tag (order_show_path) in place of your url /orders/...

Comment: You could do that, but since you're in javascript (and it's dynamic) you'll have limited access to rails variables for that purpose. $.getJSON("<%= orders_path %>"+orderId+".json"

Comment: And that's the problem, it does not replace that tag. It seems that it completely ignoring it, what should I do now?

Comment: Can you give more details? orders_path is not being output? Is it a valid route? Could be order_path depending on what you named your controller. If you do a "bundle exec rake routes" you'll get the names of your routes you can use. If you don't see "orders" then that is not a route.

Comment: I tried alert("<%= orders_list_path %>"); and it just alerts literally <%= orders.... So the ruby tags are not replaced by anything. Should javascript be somewhere else and with .erb extension?

Comment: Is your js file an erb, or a simple js file? Obviously, if it's just a javascript file being included on the page, your Ruby/Rails code is not going to be evaluated at all because there is no concept of it in js. You can either include part of the code in your html.erb file, or use a js.erb file so that you have access to those variables, etc. You can find plenty of links about how js.erb works.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?